# Conditions for a parametric curve to avoid self-intersection?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves, euclidean-geometry

Suppose a planar curve $C$ is defined by parametric
equations in $t$: $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.
Are there conditions on these two functions that guarantee
that $C$ does not self-intersect?

For example,
the [Maclaurin trisectrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinTrisectrix.html)
can be defined by
$$x(t) = \frac{t^2-3}{t^2+1},
\;\;\;\;\;y(t)=\frac{t(t^2-3)}{t^2+1}$$
and it self-intersects:

---

[image: MathWorld]

---

So, rational functions do not suffice to imply non-self-intersection.
Pointers would be appreciated—Thanks!

Comment: $x(t) = \frac{t^{3}-3}{t^{2}+1}$? Shouldn't it be $x(t) = \frac{t^{2}-3}{t^{2}+1}$

Comment: In fact, high degree rational functions (at least over complex numbers) will generally lead to curves with self-intersection. This is because a generic high-degree rational curve in $\mathbb P^2$ has many nodes. Thus to avoid the intersections in the affine patch, you would need to have all of the singularities at the line at infinity.

Comment: The injectivity of both functions x(t) and y(t) provides a sufficient condition to ensure that the curve does not self-intersect.

Comment: Thanks, @J.H.S., for the exponent correction in the trisectrix example.

Comment: @J.H.S.: Nice observation re injectivity! But of course (as is implicit in your comment), that is not necessary, e.g., $(x(t),y(t))= (\sin t, t)$ is not self intersecting but $\sin t$ is not injective.

Comment: If the Gauss map lies in a hemisphere, then I think there can't be self-intersections. This generalizes J.H.S.'s condition, since if $x(t)$ or $y(t)$ is injective, then the curve will be a graph, so will have tangent directions lying in a hemisphere.

Comment: @IanAgol: In order for the Gauss map criterion to work, you have to assume, in addition, that the curve has no cusps.  Otherwise, you could have a curve with two cusps and one self-intersection that has Gauss map contained in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of a point.  A suitable example can be made by setting $\bigl(x'(t),y'(t)\bigr) = \bigl((1-t^2), t(1-t^2)^2/h(t^2)\bigr)$ where $h$ is a positive function of $t^2$ that grows sufficiently fast.

Comment: Here's an explicit rational example of the kind of cusped curve with small Gauss map that I had in mind: $$ x(t) = t - \frac{x^3}3\ ,\quad\quad y(t) = \lambda\ \frac{4+13t^2+2t^4+t^6}{(1+t^2)^2}\ , $$ where $\lambda>0$ is a small constant.  This curve has one self-intersection, where $t= \pm\sqrt3$.

Comment: Sorry!...Make that $$ x(t) = t - \frac{t^3}3$$  in the above formula.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to formulate conditions *for* self-intersection; a necessary such condition is, that the average turning angle exceeds $2\pi$ in at least one subinterval of the parameter range.

Comment: Ah, yes, Robert, I meant a curve in which the derivative is non-vanishing (I assumed this was implicit in defining the Gauss map - I was thinking of the Gauss map defined using the unit tangent vector, rather than the unit normal vector). Another way of phrasing it is that the tangent vector always has non-zero inner product with a particular vector, which means that it has 1-1 projection to a line parallel to that vector. So this is really just a variation on JHS's condition.

Comment: This might be a bit silly: there are no self-intersections if there exists a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $t\mapsto f(x(t),y(t))$ is injective. The condition should also be necessary provided $(\dot x, \dot y)$ doesn't vanish on any open interval.

Comment: @ManfredWeis:  I think you mean that the total turning angle exceeds $\pi$, since this is what is necessary (if the parametrization is an immersion, anyway).  You don't have to go all the way to $2\pi$.  The *average* turning angle doesn't tell you that much if you don't know much about the size of the interval.  Ian: The "Gauss map" in my example, in the sense of the map of the tangent direction to the unit circle, is smooth and well-defined, since $dy/dx = t(1-t^2)/h(t^2)$.

Comment: @RobertBryant You are right Robert, my error is probably due to some occupation with smooth Jordan curves; the correct condtion should also take into account the angle of intersection.

Answer (score 3):

By its very nature, this question cannot expect a definitive answer but here are some suggestions.

1. For a curve with parametrisation of the form $(\int^t(u)du,f(t))$ for a function $f$ of one variable it is the case if $f$ is injective or, better, if and only if $\int^s f(u)du\neq \int^t f(u)du$ whenever $f(s)=f(t)$.
2. Many important curves have parametrisations of this form (circle, cycloid, catenary, ....).
3. In a certain sense "every" curve has such a parametrisation.  More precisely, consider the curve with parametrisation $(x(s),y(s))$.  Since self-intersection is preserved under diffeomorphisns, we can suppose that the curve lies in the upper half plane.  Under the new parameter $t$ where the latter is, as a function of $s$, the primitive of $\frac{x'(s)}{y(s)}$, the parametrisation will have the above form.
4. Of course, this will not work universally since this $t$ will not always be a 
   reparametrisation but it will be in many concrete situations, e.g., if $x$ is strictly monotone.

Comment: Just a small remark: the condition in point 1 is actually independent of the fact that $F$ is a primitive of $f$.

Comment: True, but the point of my remark was that this condition depends only on ONE function $f$, rather than on the pair of functions $x$ and $y$. I should probably have written $$\int^s f(u)dt \neq \int^t f(u)du.$$

Comment: have edited my answer to avoid the impression that it was tautological